# Silverlight 4 Assembly Caching for Project References

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have several Silverlight utility and control projects that I re-use in several different applications with-in my web application. These are all worked on in the same solution. Each Silverlight application has it's own page.

Example Setup

- Utilities
- CommonResources
  I've strong name keyed and created extmap for these projects, but the dll's are still in the xaps. The version is defnied as 1.0.0.0 in the assembly.cs.

  CommonResources
      1.0.0.0
      {public key here}
      Silverlight.Common.CommonResources.dll

These all reference Utilities and CommonResources
 - ManageFoo
 - ManageBar
 - etc

Can I assembly cache the utilities and CommonResources dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try adding an XML file (e.g. named Common.CommonResources.extmap.xml) to the CommonResources project, and set “Copy to Output Directory” to “Copy if newer”, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <assembly>
    <name>Common.CommonResources</name>
    <version>*.*.*.*</version>
    <publickeytoken>*</publickeytoken>
    <relpath>Common.CommonResources.dll</relpath>
    <extension downloadUri="Common.CommonResources.zip" />
  </assembly>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Changing Copy to Output Directory worked! Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you couldn't in this scenario. In fact it seems to be the ideal candidate.

You'll need to make sure you generate `extmap` files for your Utilities and CommonResources dlls. The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <assembly>
    <name>System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit</name>
    <version>2.0.5.0</version>
    <publickeytoken>31bf3856ad364e35</publickeytoken>
    <relpath>System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit.dll</relpath>
    <extension downloadUri="System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit.zip" />
  </assembly>

</manifest>
```

and has the name of the form:

```
<dllname>.extmap.dll
```

and must be in the same location as the dll itself.

Comment: +1 That would work, but fzlin uses VS to automatically do it with that setting, so I accepted his answer.

Comment: @Aligned - no problem. That's what the accepted answer is for - to show the one that helped you the most.